# AWS cannot signed CloudFront urls PEM error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using NodeJS to get a signed URL from Cloudfront... I have the credentials to get them but I'm always getting an error, it tells me the credentials are wrong, I'm using this library.

aws-cloudfront-sign

```
var cfsign = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');

var signingParams = {
  keypairId: process.env.PUBLIC_KEY,
  privateKeyString: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  expireTime: 1426625464599
}

// Generating a signed URL
var signedUrl = cfsign.getSignedUrl(
  'http://example.cloudfront.net/image.png', 
  signingParams
);
```

[image]

Obviously I have replaced example.cloudfront with the name of my distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.. you must add the break lines with \n in a variable

```
const pk = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nABDECASFAFSAS\n
```